# Access struct fields through interface

Tags: go

Regardless of whether is this an idiomatic go or not, in some situations we want to access an **underlying** concrete value of an **interface** value. here is an example:

I have these structs and interface:

```
type person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

type secretAgent struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

type Human interface {
    speak()
}

func (p person) speak() {}
func (p secretAgent) speak() {}
```

And I also have this function:

```
func bar(h Human) {
    fmt.Println(h.name, "is sent to bar!!") // <-- name is not accessible 
}

p1 := person{"foo bar", 34}
bar(p1)
```

How can I access struct fields in this situation?

Answer (score -2):

For any one who might be interesting it this question, I found the solution.

Regardless of whether is this an idiomatic go or not, because interface can't find the exact type you are trying to access through it, you should **assert** the type of interface value.

> A type assertion provides access to an interface value's underlying concrete value.

so in my case the implementation would be like this:

```
func bar(h Human) {
    switch h := h.(type) { // <-- this is type assertion
    case person:
        fmt.Println(h.name, "is sent to bar!!") // <-- just has access to person
    case secretAgent:
        fmt.Println(h.name, "is sent to bar!!") // <-- has access to secretAgent
    }
}
```